# How to change tab content according to the selected tab

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, tabs

I have extracted following code from an already developed script. I need to change this text according to clicked item.

As an example if someone clicked `Home` button I need to change this div to some other text like you have clicked "Home" likewise. Simply I need the navigation in same page to different text portions.

This is providing what I need exactly without one function. I could see that following text portion is static for every time.

```
<div style="padding:0 16px">
  <h3>Subnav/dropdown menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
  <p>Hover over the "about", "services" or "partners" link to see the sub navigation menu.</p>
</div>
```

I hope this could be done using jQuery/JavaScript.

Thanks in advance!!

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.subnav {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.subnav .subnavbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.subnav-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.subnav-content a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.subnav-content a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}

.subnav:hover .subnav-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn">About <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
      <div class="subnav-content">
        <a href="#company">Company</a>
        <a href="#team">Team</a>
        <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn">Services <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
      <div class="subnav-content">
        <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
        <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
        <a href="#package">Package</a>
        <a href="#express">Express</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn">Partners <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
      <div class="subnav-content">
        <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <div style="padding:0 16px">
    <h3>Subnav/dropdown menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
    <p>Hover over the "about", "services" or "partners" link to see the sub navigation menu.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I've converted your code to a snippet demo so we can see what we're working with. However, it's not clear what you want to change. If it's the top level menu item, that would be a very disruptive UX. The size variation would have things jumping around. Please revise to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // This is classes that you need to add for it to work

     <p class="paragraph">Hover over the "about", "services" or 
 "partners" link to see the sub navigation menu.</p>
     <a class="home" href="#home">Home</a>   


 // And this is your javascript code

    const home= document.querySelector('.home')
    const paragraph=document.querySelector('.paragraph')
    
    home.onclick=function(){
    paragraph.innerHTML="You are now in a home page"
    }

 // Hope it helps!
```

Comment: You could copy the snippet demo down from the question and integrate your solution to demonstrate.